# Type hugeint is not defined in MonetDB

Tags: python, django, monetdb

I am facing one problem while running the query from Django-Python. I am getting error "Type hugeint is not defined" using database Monetdb. Can anyone suggest why this error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MonetDB documentation](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/BuiltinTypes)

> HUGEINT is only available since the Jul2015 release and on platforms with a C-compiler that supports the __int128 or __int128_t data type (e.g., recent gcc, clang, & icc on Linux or MacOS X)

Could it be that you don't satisfy these requirements ?